# VBA - terminating Internet Explorer processes via Shell

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Including a line which terminates IE instances causes an automation error on `Do Until` or my macro freeze. The line is used to make sure no old processes sit in the memory.

The problem doesn't appear when I enter debugging, run the Shell line and wait a bit, so that probably IE can load before executing next lines.

I wonder is there is any way of detecting whether IE application is ready. Replacing `name='iexplore.exe'` with `name='iexplore.exe *32'` doesn't make the 32 bit processes disappear, maybe one disappears and to kill other instances a loop could be used?

```
Shell ("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c wmic process where name='iexplore.exe' call terminate")

Link = "http://www.example.com"
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate Link

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMIC just calls objects. You can call them direct.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.name & " " & objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "iexplore.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

It's name is IExplore.exe no matter which bitness.

To access shell folders (Explorer and Internet Explorer windows [historical reasons]). This refreshes all shell windows every 5 secs. I've added a msgbox in.

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Do 
        Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
        Count = 0
        For Each window in AllWindows
            msgbox window.locationname
            window.refresh2 3
`To close a shell window
`window.close
            Count = Count + 1
        Next
        If Count = 0 then Exit Do
        Wscript.sleep 5000
    Loop
```